# MultiPart with memory issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, multipart

Upload image is not working.
It has a memory issue.

When I call the API, my app stops. Then the GC is called multiple times and a TimeOut exception is thrown.

I considered compressing the image file with `Bitmap.Compress`, but, calling `compress` also takes a lot of memory.

I don't know what the best way to upload an image is. 
Can you guys help me?

This is `ApiInterface`.

```
@Multipart
@POST("memo/update")
fun updateMemo(
        @Header("token") token: String,
        @Part("content") content: RequestBody,
        @Part("location") location: RequestBody,
        @Part("id") id : RequestBody,         
        @Part imgFile: MultipartBody.Part?)
        : Observable<JsonObject>
```

This method return `MultiPart.Body`.

```
private fun toMultipartBody(uri: Uri?): MultipartBody.Part? {
    uri?.let {
        val file = File(it.path)

        val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)

        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(memo::memoFile.name, file.name, requestFile)
    }
    return null
}
```

And it's a method call API.

```
 private fun updateMemo() {
    disposables.add(
            service.updateMemo(
                    TipTapApplication.getAccessToken(),
                    toRequestBody(memo.content),
                    toRequestBody(memo.location),
                    toRequestBody(memo.latitude),
                    toRequestBody(memo.longitude),
                    toRequestBody(memo.id.toString()),
                    toMultipartBody(imgUri))

               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<JsonObject>() {
                        override fun onNext(t: JsonObject) {
                        }

                        override fun onComplete() {

                            finish()
                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }))
}
```

Comment: Few questions. Is it working properly for small images? Is this happening only when you are trying to upload multiple images?

Comment: @Debanjan I'm trying to upload just one image. When I try to upload image that over 130~160kb, GC is called.